# Starting GPSD on boot on debian VM

Tags: debian, gpsd

I am using gpsd on a debian VM (on windows host) to automatically start logging gps data on system reboot (the VM launches through as shell script).

I am having issues where sometimes the cgps screen is completely blank and gpspipe output no data other than time. I am fairly certain that this is a issue with the gps signal but I'm not sure if to make my program more "robust" I should edit the /etc/default/gpsd file to initiate on startup?

Currently the fields in that file are empty other than USBAUTO = "true" but could there be problems if I dont add the device to the devices field? I currently initiate the program by just running gpspipe on system boot. I just want to know whether I should update the gpsd file to have all my device information and whether leaving that out could cause problems, thanks.